# In the movie Se7en, SLOTH thoughts

Tags: plot-explanation, se7en

The SLOTH victim, exactly why was he to be tortured to death "this" way?

Are we supposed to know what happened to his left hand, and what exactly are those tubes in his right arm?

Are we to surmise he was made a heroin addict then experience withdrawal? Am I thinking about this too much?

Answer (score 2):

> Are we supposed to know what happened to his left hand, and what exactly are those tubes in his right arm?

His left hand seems to have been removed by John Doe. Remember that the reason the police are visiting the Sloth victim are because his fingerprints were identified at the Greed murder scene.

The tubes are an IV line carrying nutrients, fluids, and whatever drugs John Doe was using to keep the victim alive and placid for the year he was trapped in the apartment.

Answer (score -3):

The Sloth death isn't exactly clear...generally we're supposed to assume that deaths to the victims are supposed to be a sort of...'poetic' justice and a part of John Doe's larger spectacle and how each represents their respective sin.

We don't know very much with him, besides he was forced on drugs and rotted away in bed for a year or something. He should represent slothness (even this sin as a description isn't exactly clear)...whatever that means. And I assume in this particular case it should be the laziness. The complete and utter lack of doing nothing and wasting all possibilities on nothing.

Doe shows this by having a person 'presumably' be able to escape, but does not and simple wastes his body and brain. But Se7en has several missing links....this particular one is probably one of them.

However I would say yes, don't think about it so much...the film is 25 years old now...there are bound to be some plot holes. :)

Comment: Why does the age of the film mean it will have plot holes?

Comment: @HorusKol The argument of the statement is, we've had 25 years to pick it apart and analyse and/or compare to movies that have done something similar, ripped off and or both and did it better. There are bound to be things to be found that don't make sense.

Comment: Why? Strange statement to make with no evidence to back it up.

Comment: The argument "it's old so it's bad" is simply horrible. -1 for this.

Comment: @Yasskier you have a gross misunderstanding of what my sentence means. I do not think the movie is bad because its as old as my nieces and nephews nor do i think its bad at all. -1 for reading skills.

Comment: "the film is 25 years old now...there are bound to be some plot holes. :)"  = since the movie is old, it hasn't been written in a good way.  It is simply a really bad argument.

Comment: Your leap of logic is beyond comprehension and shared by you alone. To reiterate, my sentence has nothing to do with how good the movie is, there are no adjectives or context to suggest otherwise, beyond ones you made up yourself and conjecture onto my own. It simply states it has plot holes and we’ve had many years to look for them.

Comment: I'm not saying that you said that the movie was bad or not enjoyable - you can enjoy even horrible movies and/or movies with plot holes. I'm downowting because you say that "it is old, so it has plotholes"=> "old movies have plotholes". It is your opinion, You are entitled to it opinion as I am entitled to mine, which is "it is a horrible argument".

Comment: You literally said, I said the movie was bad in your *first* comment. Your arguement is inherently wrong. All movies have plot holes, when you dig for 25 years you'll eventually find something.

Comment: @morbo This 'leap of logic' you reference: it's not quite a leap at all.  And I think we all think that this answer lacks any real analysis.  The first three paragraphs make no strong assertion, and really do not constitute a bona fide answer.  Your only clear assertion is made in your last paragraph.  At the end of the day we are left only with a mere comment, and not a good one at that.  It's no surprise is this is receiving downvotes.